# Stimmt es, dass das Wort "besser" von "böse" kommt?

Tags: etymology

jemand sagte mir, dass das Wort "besser" etymologisch von "böse" kommt und dass es in der altdeutschen (germanischen) Sprache kein Wort für "schlecht" und für "böse" gab. Stimmt das?

Liebe Grüße
Miriam

Answer (score 3):

Der althochdeutsche Stamm für *böse, übel* lautet *balo, bala*, vermutlich ist das vom lateinischen *malum, mala* abgeleitet.

Das Wort *böse* kommt hingegen vom althochdeutschen Wort *bōsi*, das man auch heute noch in Wörtern wie *Bosheit* findet. Die eigentliche Bedeutung ist *nichtig, wertlos, feige*. Der *Bōsiwiht — Bösewicht* ist *ein Nichtsnutz, ein wertloser Kerl, ein Feigling*.

Das Wort *besser* kommt hingegen von *buozen — bessern, büßen*.

[Siehe Köbler, Gerhard: Althochdeutsches Wörterbuch](http://www.koeblergerhard.de/ahd/ahd_b.html)

Comment: Damit wäre Zweifels frei erwiesen, dass *buozen* und *bōsi* sich schon sehr ähnlich stehen (AHD z /s/). Und weiter?

Answer (score 1):

Nein, etymologisch kommt *besser* nicht von "böse", sondern ist mit dem Wort **Buße** verwandt. Auch heute sagt man noch "Ich gelobe Besserung".

Ungefähr ab dem 15. Jahrhundert war das Wort (Ver-)Besserung gleichbedeutend mit '*gerichtliche Buße, Ersatz, Entschädigung*'.

Comment: Wieso "kommt von" Buße? *Besser* und *Buße* sind verwandt, aber sie stehen nicht in einem Ableitungsverhältnis.

Comment: Korrekt, danke. Habe den Satz umformuliert.